# Using array methods changes my array contents

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

In my angular code i use `array.some()`to find if the element exists in array, but while running `array.some()` is changing the original array content. its totally unexpected that `array.some()` changes the array content.

```
let temp = this.mainArray.find(val => val.id == this.myId);
```

In my case the contents of `mainArray` gets changed when the above code executes

Comment: Can you share how you're using `.some()`

Comment: codes in the callback are changing the array content not `array.some` did.

Comment: You need to show the `.some()` code that you claim is changing the array and please provide a reproducible case.  Your `.find()` code that you show will NOT by itself change the array.

Answer (score 0):

As Some returns a Boolean, its result is commonly used in conditional statements.

```js
mainarray =[1,2,3,4]

const isCheckArrayValueContain = mainarray
  .some(item => item == 5);
  

console.log(isCheckArrayValueContain);
```

Some’s first argument is a callback function that exposes these parameters:

- value --> (the current element)
- index --> (the element’s index - sometimes used with Filter)
- array --> (the array we are looping - rarely used)

Inside the body of the function we need to return an expression
which will evaluate to a Boolean (true or false)

**Some’s second argument thisArg allows the this context to be changed**